# "Log in using Google" uses Chrome without asking

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app

If Chrome is installed, "Log in using Google" always uses Chrome, even if that option is disabled in the settings. Unlike the Facebook button, it doesn't ask, either.

This is somewhat inconvenient for people who have Chrome installed just for testing and rely on iCloud Keychain or 1Password integration in Safari for passwords.

Version 1.1.0.125

Comment: Make sure the "Use Chrome" setting in the Stack Exchange app itself is disabled: http://i.stack.imgur.com/16Pv0.png

Comment: I did, and it was. It was a fresh install, too. I think it might be the google-plus-ios-sdk favoring Chrome.

Comment: If you have iOS 8 maybe it's just one of its many bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in assuming this is `google-plus-ios-sdk`'s doing.  Unfortunately the authentication process is a black box.  From `GPPSignIn.h`:

```
// This class signs the user in with Google. It provides single sign-on
// via the Google+ app (if installed), Chrome for iOS (if installed), or Mobile
// Safari.
```

The only control we have over it is to disable use of the Google+ app.

If I were bold, I would swizzle `-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]` and reject Chrome URL's while authenticating but who know what that might break. We're just going to have to accept the fact that Google thinks we're super excited about all of their apps.